# Can gyroscope work in zero gravity?

Tags: gravity, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, equivalence-principle, gyroscopes

Most ships have two or more gyroscopes to balance on water, man made satellites uses [gyroscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope) for orientation as they fall around earth. All these applications seems to be associated with gravity, therefore how can a gyroscope works in zero gravity?

Comment: yeah, sure.  why wouldn't they?

Comment: To conclude a spacecraft in zero gravity uses gyroscope to (a) orientate itself in space (b) find its orientation in space (c) all of the above (d) none of the above. Which is the correct answer to fit into the statement.

Comment: but my question was "why wouldn't" a gyroscope work in zero gravity?  there is no reason they would not.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson is that question meant for me or the community?

Comment: it was for you.  i cannot understand why you would wonder "how can a gyroscope works in zero gravity?"  it's the contrary that you should wonder about.  what reason would you think it cannot?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson ships on the sea use motorized gyroscopes to combat the raging waves and communication satellite orbiting around the Earth use gyroscopes to maintain and point their signal towards the receiving stations on Earth. I imagine in a zero gravity if a gyroscope is spinning upright on its axis perpendicular to a flat and even plate which is accelerating in the direction of the gyroscope... what will happens if I try to topple the spinning gyroscope (behave like a spinning top)?

Comment: okay, ships at sea use [**gimbal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal) to "combat the raging waves".  the gyroscope is there to point in the same direction (such as the north star) at all times, but as the ship rolls and yaws, it's the gimbal that deals with that problem.  a gyroscope on a satellite does **not** point their signal toward a receiving station on Earth.  not even for geo-synchronous satellites.  if it weren't for effects of general relativity, a gyroscope on a satellite would point to the same distant star, even as the satellite revolves around the Earth.

Comment: Oh I see I didn't know about gimbal, I thought it was the doing of gyroscope. Thanks for clearing my thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gyroscopes depend on the conservation of angular momentum.  Orientation and navigation gyroscopes are finely balanced/symmetrized so that gravitational fields will not exert external torque and modify the angular momentum.

As the container which holds the gyroscope moves, a [gimbal mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal) allows the gyroscope to maintain a constant rotational axis orientation.  Sensors measure the changes between the container and the axis of rotation so that navigation parameters are known.

Even if there was no gravitational field, the angular momentum (and hence the orientation of the axis) would be constant.

Comment: user, take a look at Bill's answer here.  but your question had a serious questionable premise that made it impossible to answer directly.

Answer (score 1):

> man made satellites uses gyroscope for orientation as they fall around
>   earth. All these applications **seem to be associated with gravity**,
>   therefore how can a gyroscope work in zero gravity?

You are probably confusing or identifying the property of a gyroscope with the phenomenon of [*precession*](https://youtu.be/8H98BgRzpOM?t=27)
The bicycle wheel (gyroscope) doesn't fall down and **precesses** because the force of gravity is deviated from the vertical axis to the horizontal one. What you see is gravity pushing the wheel around instead of pushing it downward.

But this happens because of the [*property of a gyroscope*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope#Properties) to oppose any change in the plane of rotation and shift it by 90°

This property is univerally valid and works in any conditions and also in zero gravity.

You can see [here](http://www.our-space.org/materials/states-of-matter/gyroscopes) what happens in a spacecraft at zero gravity. The gyroscope does not rotate on its center of mass when is hit/pushed on one tip. You can see that, when it's not spinning, it rotates, exactly like on earth.

The only difference is that, if you hang it on one tip, it will stand still, it will not precess because no force is acting on it in any direction

Answer (score 1):

A gyroscope rotor does not possess the property of weight in zero gravity, but the rotor still possesses the property of mass and the associated properties of inertia, and, (when in circular motion), angular velocity and momentum so the gyroscopic principles of conservation of angular momentum fully apply and so the gyroscope performs exactly as it would in a gravity field, i.e. it maintains a stable directional orientation of its axis of rotation.

The only difference is that in a gravity field, (where there is no nett angular component of force on the rotor's axis), the gyroscope body (i.e. the closed system), as a whole would fall towards the centre of the distortion of the space-time continuum whilst maintaining its axial orientation.

In a zero gravity environment, the closed system would simply float and, in the absence of any unbalanced external influencing force, would maintain its axial orientation as explained above.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQb-N486mA4

Answer (score -3):

When a gyroscope is outside of a gravity field, the spinning disc has no weight. To my mind this means that no centrafugal force or any other force is produced so there is no effect. If you had a gyroscope on earth with no flywheel it would be the same thing, would that work !!

Comment: Centrifugal force is caused by mass (inertia), not weight. Do you know the difference?

Answer (score -3):

Mass without inertia means no gravity while absence of gravity means no inertial force. i.e. Inertia = 0(!), Accordingly, a Gyroscope can not work as gyroscope without any gravitational force. on the other hand, there is no substance in the universe that has 0 gravitational force, it would not exist in the universe. The gravitational force in the universe may have different physical property.